# magento 1.9 how to show product of category

Tags: magento-1.9, home-page

I need show product of categry in home page

I test this code

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" category_id="55" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

but not showing the product of category in home page
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento admin panel go to CMS> Pages>Home page.

```
{{block  type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

In case you want to control the number of columns in product listing, please use the following code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Where the `column_count` value is the number of columns.

Navigate to System->Permissions->Blocks.

Click on the Add new block button.

Specify your Block Name, which is: `catalog/product_list`.

And allow the Block using the `YES/No` Dropdown list

Comment: thank you for answer This code answers
But that's what I do not want
This code is in the frame
When I enter the category, it is very tidy. I want to be like that

Comment: I want the home page to look like a category page

Comment: please update your question. Exactly, what do you want?

Answer (score 1):

Go to CMS->PAGES->HOME:

```
{{block  type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Call the above code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it may happen with you in system.log
 Security problem: catalog/product_list has not been whitelisted.

You need to give the permission for your block

Go to `System->Permissions->Blocks`.

Click add new block where block name `catalog/product_list` and **isAllowed -> Yes**

Now save. Clear cache. Hope this will solve your problem

And hope this will work for you

Comment: I want the home page to look like a category page